# How to combine the same id and mrege the data into one record?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database structure like so:

```
Car
 - id   
 - carname
 - image
 - category
 - status

Parts
 - partid
 - partname

CarParts
 - carpartid
 - carid(fk)
 - partid(fk)
 - amountid(fk)

Category
 - id
 - categoryname

Amount
 - amountid
 - amountvalue
```

Right now this is what I am working on:

```
SELECT * FROM carparts
INNER JOIN car on carparts.carpartid = car.id 

INNER JOIN parts on parts.partid = carparts.carpartid

INNER JOIN amount on amount.amountid = carparts.amountid where status = 1
```

This returns duplicate records when there is more than one carpart in the carparts table. How can I combine the carparts.id and car.id to one row but still have multiple partname for that one record?

Comment: Hi i have tried to use group by which gives one back but i cant have multiple part names for one record?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM car left join  carparts on car.id = carparts.carpartid 
left join  parts on parts.partid = carparts.carpartid
left join amount on amount.amountid = carparts.amountid where status = 1
group by car.id
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't just post code, explain what it does and why it's the right thing to do.

Comment: This does not give me multiple partnames for one record

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
SELECT group_concat(parts.partname) as parts FROM car left join  carparts on car.id = carparts.carpartid 
left join  parts on parts.partid = carparts.carpartid
left join amount on amount.amountid = carparts.amountid where status = 1
group by car.id
```

Since we need to combine records, we are doing it via group by clause. Also since we need multiple records in one row, we are using group_concat to concatenate multiple results.
P.S : There is some limitation on number of values returned by group_concat ?

Comment: Hi this only returns parts i still want the rest of the data

Comment: @JakeDawsen : You can retrieve other columns as well like : 
Select col1,col2 , group_concat(parts.partname) as parts....